# write custom Marshall and Unmarshaller for proto buf type in golang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have custom type that I wrote my own Marshall and Unmarshaller
And the problem is I Want to do the same using protobuf

I just want to implement the same using protobuf, so that I can implement my own Marshall and Unmarshaller

```
syntax="proto3";

package main;

message NullInt64{
    bool Valid = 1;
    int64 Int64 = 2;
}
```

In the way that if the Valid value is false in return the `null` string

```
type NullInt64 struct {
    Int64 int64
    Valid bool
}

// MarshalJSON try to marshaling to json
func (nt NullInt64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if nt.Valid {
        return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`%d`, nt.Int64)), nil
    }

    return []byte("null"), nil
}

// UnmarshalJSON try to unmarshal dae from input
func (nt *NullInt64) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    text := strings.ToLower(string(b))
    if text == "null" {
        nt.Valid = false

        return nil
    }

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &nt.Int64)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    nt.Valid = true
    return nil
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. A "null" string is not a valid protobuf. You can serialize and deserialize your `NullInt64` type to protobuf fine. Is that not sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Protoc will not generate `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` functions.

You can:

1. Use a different protobuf generator (see [gogo/protobuf](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf) and it's many [extensions](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/blob/master/extensions.md) or fork golang/protobuf to change their [generator](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/protoc-gen-go/generator/generator.go))
2. Insert your own functions into the `proto` package by adding a file to that folder. You can either hand-write or code gen these functions.